# Bootstrap columns not working as intended

Tags: html, css, menu, bootstrap-5

I would like to create a menu with bootstrap but the 'col' class doesn't seem to work as intended.
Here is the html code:

```
<div class="logo col">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="Content/Logo.png" class="logo"/></a>
</div>
<div class="menu col">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="GradientText">Accueil</a></li>
      <li><a href="Views/Portfolio.html" class="GradientText">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="Views/Contact.html" class="GradientText">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Both classes *menu* and *logo* are defined in my own css file.

Bootstrap 5.1.3 is used

Here is what it gives me: [image: How it looks in Firefox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it with a `row` class

Bootstrap 5 uses flex. `row` is the wrapper for column and provides `display: flex` property for columns to be sized accordingly.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="logo col">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" class="logo"/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu col">
     <ul >
        <li class="d-inline"><a href="index.html" class="GradientText">Accueil</a></li>
        <li class="d-inline"><a href="Views/Portfolio.html" class="GradientText">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="d-inline"><a href="Views/Contact.html" class="GradientText">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```